# Can not create backup of Firebird database because of the errors

Tags: firebird

At the time of backup firebird database (gbak -g -ig) I have the following error:

```
gbak:    writing data for table ORDERS 
gbak: ERROR:message length error (encountered 532, expected 528) 
gbak: ERROR:gds_$receive failed 
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

When I'm using **gfix** with different parameters (-v -full, -mend, -ignore), I have the message:

```
Summary of validation errors
        Number of index page errors     : 540
```

In **firebird.log** file I see the lines:

```
PC (Server) Thu Sep 20 08:37:01 2018
    Database: E:\...GDB
    Index 2 is corrupt on page 134706 level 1. File: ..\..\..\src\jrd\validation.cpp, line: 1699
     in table COMPONENTS (197)
```

However, the database works OK without problems.

Please help me to fix the error and make a backup.
(I need the backup to migrate to on 64bit server).

Comment: I suggest you post your question to the firebird-support mailing list; you're more likely to get help for this there.

Comment: "the database works OK without problems" - when you program accesses other data, not the data residing in the problematic places. The it walks around the "cracks in the ground". However gbak tries to read the entirety of the databases including both valid data and invalid one and falls into the cracks.